# Gremlin throwing an error while executing the lambda

Tags: gremlin, amazon-neptune

```
g.V().hasLabel("OperatingSystem")
            .filter(Lambda.predicate("{it.get().property('name').startsWith('xyz')}")).out("dpend_on")
            .as("ast").out("depend_on").hasLabel("abc")
```

results in an error:

> java.util.concurrent.CompletionException:
>   org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.driver.exception.ResponseException: Query parsing failed at line 1, character position at 0, error message : mismatched input '[' expecting {'''', '""', 'g'}
>
> at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.reportJoin(CompletableFuture.java:375)
>   at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.join(CompletableFuture.java:1934)
>   at org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.driver.ResultSet.one(ResultSet.java:107)
>   at org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.driver.ResultSet$1.hasNext(ResultSet.java:159)
>   at org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.driver.ResultSet$1.next(ResultSet.java:166)
>   at org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.driver.ResultSet$1.next(ResultSet.java:153)
>   at org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.driver.remote.DriverRemoteTraversal$TraverserIterator.next(DriverRemoteTraversal.java:142)
>   at org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.driver.remote.DriverRemoteTraversal$TraverserIterator.next(DriverRemoteTraversal.java:127)
>   at org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.driver.remote.DriverRemoteTraversal.nextTraverser(DriverRemoteTraversal.java:108)
>   at org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.process.remote.traversal.step.map.RemoteStep.processNextStart(RemoteStep.java:80)
>   at org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.process.traversal.step.util.AbstractStep.next(AbstractStep.java:128)
>   at org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.process.traversal.step.util.AbstractStep.next(AbstractStep.java:38)
>   at org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.process.traversal.util.DefaultTraversal.next(DefaultTraversal.java:200)

Comment: Not sure if this has anything to do with it but it looks like you misspelled "dpend_on" in the out step directly following the lambda

Comment: g.V().hasLabel("OperatingSystem")
        .filter(Lambda.predicate("{it.get().property('name').startsWith('xyz')}")).count().next();

Comment: g.V().hasLabel("OperatingSystem")
        .filter(Lambda.predicate("{it.get().property('name').startsWith('Windows')}")).count().next();

Comment: Still it is not working :( .

Comment: You can simulate a `startsWith` behavior using a `between` step and avoiding needing a lambda. For example `has('some_key',between('abc','abd'))`

Answer (score 2):

I just saw that you were using Amazon Neptune.  Neptune does not support Lambda steps per the documentation here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/neptune/latest/userguide/access-graph-gremlin-differences.html

Comment: It is not supporting simple Anonymous class to then how to apply filter query to it or how to apply has with predicate. So how to write query like startWith ,contains etc